# Hibernate sql query error

Tags: sql, database, hibernate

following is the query:

```
    Query q = getSession().createQuery("FROM secroles 
                           WHERE secroles.SR_ORG = :srOrg , 
                                 secroles.SR_PROFILE= :srUser, 
                                 ISDELETED=:isDeleted");
```

error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 37 [FROM secroles WHERE SR_ORG = :srOrg , SR_PROFILE= :srUser , ISDELETED = :ISDELETED]
```

complete function:

```
public String getSecroleByOrgNID(Organization srOrg, Profile srUser){try {
        System.out.println("bug is here0");
        begin();
        Query q = getSession().createQuery("FROM secroles WHERE secroles.SR_ORG = :srOrg , secroles.SR_PROFILE= :srUser , ISDELETED=:isDeleted");
        q.setParameter("srOrg", srOrg);
        q.setParameter("srOrg", srUser);
        q.setBoolean("isDeleted", false);
        Secroles sr = (Secroles) q.uniqueResult();
        Roletable rt = sr.getSrRole();
        commit();
        return rt.getRoleName();
    } catch( HibernateException e ) {
        rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Could not assign role\n Message: "+e.getMessage());
    }
return null;

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put `,` instead of `AND`, I presume.

Also you should use class property names not column names. So probably `secroles.srOrg` instead of `secroles.SR_ORG`

Comment: not working, getting the error:
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 37 [FROM secroles WHERE secroles.srOrg = :SR_ORGsrOrg , secroles.srUser= :SR_PROFILE , ISDELETED = :ISDELETED]

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error? Are you using property names as I suggested? 'Cause your names look like column names. What I suggest - assign your query to the variable, and print it. Then post output with exact error message.

Comment: Also what is secroles? It should be class name.

Comment: initializing the variable to null and then assigned query to the variable and getting nothing in the output.

Comment: In HQL you should speak classes and properties language. Not tables and columns. Use its mapped class name instead and corresponding properties.

Comment: thanks mate it worked...correct that worked is
Query q = getSession().createQuery("FROM Secroles as s WHERE s.srOrg = :srOrg AND s.srUser = :srUser AND s.isDeleted=:isDeleted");

Answer (score 2):

Use AND instead of "," for multiple clauses. Refer to the documentation on how to use `WHERE` clause: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

```
FROM secroles 
WHERE secroles.SR_ORG = :srOrg AND
      secroles.SR_PROFILE= :srUser AND
      ISDELETED=:isDeleted
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you bind the same parameter twice using different variables according to the code above. I'm pretty sure that won't do what you expect.

```
    q.setParameter("srOrg", srOrg);
    q.setParameter("srOrg", srUser);
```